# How to select multiple columns from matrix in Julia programming?

Tags: julia

For a matrix

```
M = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 8 7 6; 5 4 3 2]
```

How can I select the first and the third column to form?

```
[1 2 3 4; 9 8 7 6]
```

Comment: I found the answer by myself: M[[1,3],:]

Comment: It's the other way around if you want columns: `M[:, [1, 3]]`, but you've got the idea. Could you add it as an answer and accept it yourself, so that this questoin doesn't appear as "Unanswered" on StackOverflow listings?

Comment: Needs formatting

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a long form answer for anyone new to Julia with a comparison to R:

Your question asks, "How can I select the first and the third *column*.." but the elements you are wanting to retrieve are actually the first and third row
"1 2 3 4; 9 8 7 6"
To do this in Julia remember that the colon operator indicates all rows/columns and that you select specific rows/columns using brackets '[,]' within the matrix brackets e.g. to select all rows of the first and third columns use:

M[:,[1,3]]

To select all columns of the first and third rows use:

M[[1,3],:]

If you are reading this and you are trying to come across from R one equivalent procedure of the above would be:

c <- c(1,2,3,4)

d <- c(5,6,7,8)

e <- c(9,8,7,6)

f <- c(5,4,3,2)

my_matrix <- as.matrix(rbind(c,d,e,f))

my_matrix[,c(1,3)]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).